# Nested Wireguard routing on a mac uses host's default gateway instead of outer tunnel for the inner tunnel

Tags: macos, mac, vpn, routing, wireguard

I use `wg-quick` from `wireguard-tools` on MacOS to make a nested tunnel `host -> outer -> inner -> internet`. The issue is when I bring up the inner tunnel (after the outer one is already up), it tries to route to it through the host's default gateway and fails as my ISP is configured to block my inner server ip. Here are my configs:

Outer tunnel server:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...
Address = 10.0.0.1/32
ListenPort = 51820
PreUp = sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth+ -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth+ -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32
```

Outer tunnel client

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...
Address = 10.0.0.2/32
# MTU = 1440
# FwMark = 51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
AllowedIPs = <inner external ip>/32, 10.0.0.1/32
Endpoint = <outer external ip>:51820
```

So far everything works, if I set AllowedIPs to `0.0.0.0/0` and run `wg-quick up ./outer.conf` I can access internet through the outer server. Now setting up inner tunnel:

Server:

```
A popular VPN provider, so I assume the config is typical. I'm able to connect to it and access the internet using some unrelated test server.
```

Client:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...
Address = 10.1.0.2/32
MTU = 1380

[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = <inner external ip>:51820
```

If I run `wg-quick up ./inner.conf` it runs

```
[#] route -q -n add -inet 0.0.0.0/1 -interface utun4
[#] route -q -n add -inet 128.0.0.0/1 -interface utun4
[#] route -q -n add -inet <inner external ip> -gateway <host default gateway>
```

which is incorrect since `inner external ip` is not accessible from the host but accessible from the outer server. If I add `Table = off` to inner client config and run

```
> sudo wg show utun4 latest-handshakes
... 1700181717
```

I see that the tunnel is established and alive, I can also successfully ping . So the problem is narrowed down and is related to incorrect routes being added. How do I fix it? I also tried leaving `Table = off` and adding first 2 routes manually:

```
sudo route -q -n add -inet 0.0.0.0/1 -interface utun4
sudo route -q -n add -inet 128.0.0.0/1 -interface utun4
```

and there is already

```
[#] route -q -n add -inet <inner external ip>/32 -interface utun3
```

added by the outer tunnel. But it also fails - the internet becomes unavailable. To clarify, `utun3` is outer interface and `utun4` is inner one.

**Update:** Keeping `Table = off` and adding a route to a single server `sudo route -q -n add -inet <website>/32 -interface utun4` correctly routes traffic to the website through the inner tunnel. So looks like I just need to fix routing tables for it and everything will work.